# Android studio warning - InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember annotations

Tags: android, java-annotations

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.1 and upon building my Kotlin with Java project I got the following warning.

> InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember
> annotations. Such InnerClass annotations are ignored.
>
> Message {kind=WARNING, text=InnerClass annotations are missing
> corresponding EnclosingMember annotations. Such InnerClass annotations
> are ignored., sources=[Unknown source file]}

Here are my Gradle details.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
//buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    applicationId "org.myapp"
    versionCode generateVersionCode()
  //...
    multiDexEnabled true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

It doesn't direct me to where the issue is. How can I locate the offending code?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It may because some annotations be confused, so just add proguard rule:

*-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep @**annotation** class * {*;}*

it worked fine to me.

Comment: nice dude its realy safe me

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue temporarily, I am adding this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}
```

Will update if I find a permanent fix. [This page for configuring JUnit 5](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-running-unit-tests-with-gradle/) may also help

Comment: Cool. Id rather keep the lint checks

Comment: It's not a FIX, you're just ignoring it...!

Comment: Was blocking development, resolved for me later. If something is blocking you from building, you'll do what is necessary to unblock