# I've been having problems for 3 weeks. I can't build my project because this problems

Tags: android

### I've got the answer, but the answer can not help me. I want a detailed answer. this first problems. Program show "app:transferformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug"

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution;

    failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at
```

### second problems.

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### And,the last Problems.

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    ... 131 more
```

### This my build.gradel.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nsc.apk.herb4health"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }


    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

}




dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    implementation supportDependencies.appCompat
    implementation supportDependencies.recycler
    implementation supportDependencies.cardView
    implementation supportDependencies.kitCore

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

    // RecyclerView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

    // For Cover Flow
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.7'

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.1'

    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.2.7'

    implementation 'com.github.thomper:sweet-alert-dialog:v1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'


    implementation 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:MaterialAbout:+'
    implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:IconHandler:v2.0.0'


    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.r0adkll:deadskunk:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT'
    annotationProcessor 'org.immutables:value:2.4.4'

    //ADD Library for Stack card view
    implementation 'in.arjsna:swipecardlib:1.0.2'
    //DetailBodyhumen
    //Circle Image View
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
        exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }





    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Android Show Build Monitor.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
```

---

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

---

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex;
```

Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;

And This build.gradel (Project:Name)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.roomVersion = '1.0.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath(
                'junit:junit:4.12'
        )
        classpath(
                'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
        )
        classpath(
                'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0',
                'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.1.0'
        )
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0"
        classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
        }


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.6.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'


        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'


    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
ext {
    //App
    libraryCode = 1
    libraryVersion = "1"

    //Support and Build tools version
    compileSdk = 26
    targetSdk = 26
    minSdk = 14
    buildTools = '27.0.1'
    supportLibrary = '25.4.0'
    ftKit = '0.5.1'

    //Support Libraries dependencies
    supportDependencies = [
            support       : "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibrary}",
            appCompat     : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            recycler      : "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            cardView      : "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            kitCore       : "com.52inc:52Kit-core:${ftKit}"
    ]

}
```

I used to follow these steps, but it was not okay.
[Android studio warning - InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517898/android-studio-warning-innerclass-annotations-are-missing-corresponding-enclos)

Comment: Try this **`implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'`**

Comment: if you want to enable multidex. do not take nested defaultConfig tags. you just have to add `multiDexEnabled true` in one that is already present.

Comment: implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
        exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
    } change to implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }

Comment: And if your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher then you don't need to add multidex support library , just make sure that you have configured your application class correctly.

Comment: defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
 change to 
            multiDexEnabled true

Comment: refer this link to set your root level build.gradle https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I did follow you, but I failed. Thank you @NileshRathod

Comment: I did follow you, but I build my project failed.   @HiteshSarsava

Comment: Have you check for conflicted dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to outdated library you have imported in your project.what you can do is update all library to latest version...or make another project and find out which library is making producing a problem

Comment: Thank you very mush.I did follow you, but I build my project failed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.....Ok that was quite tricky....so the problem is with "implementation 'com.r0adkll:deadskunk:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT' " library you have imported...as per my results ... try to find updated or alternative version of it.....tell me if it works .... so i can explain how i did that

Comment: I can't find library new version more than this. If I remove this library than my app can't build.

Comment: Can you give me hint what this library do or a documentation for it

Comment: I followed form https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr 
Files java for my project https://github.com/bitotassuya/Herb4Health2/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/asus/herbs4health

Comment: So I have gone through the library....and its look like you want to implement slide-to-dismiss functionality to your Activity. But dependency you are using"com.r0adkll:deadskunk:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT" does not matchs with depandency given in library...(compile 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.0.6')

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you add an external library which may not be compatible with your compileSdkVersion .

Firstly update, cleaned and rebuilt the app, if not fixed still follow below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48531191/6920195

Comment: Can't build success.