# I've got an error when I added the truetime library in android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, proguard, android-proguard

I have added the truetime library for getting the network time, but I've got an error which I can't resolve it in android.

library:

```
implementation 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-extension-rx:2.0'
```

Error:
 Android Issues:

```
    InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember annotations. Such InnerClass annotations are ignored.
Message{kind=WARNING, text=InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember annotations. Such InnerClass annotations are ignored., sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Java Compiler:

```
The rule `-keep public class *extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation {
```

I tried as much, but it couldn't resolve it.

Please, anyone, solve this problem. It would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to `Invalidate caches> Restart` on File?

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't work out.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517898/android-studio-warning-innerclass-annotations-are-missing-corresponding-enclos).

For your convenience, I also provide the answers here:

**Solution 1:**

try updating your `gradle` to the latest version.

**Solution 2:**

add this line of code on proguard rule

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep @**annotation** class * {*;}
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517898/android-studio-warning-innerclass-annotations-are-missing-corresponding-enclos

Comment: @AnubhavGupta sorry I forgot to put the link for reference.

Comment: @AnubhavGupta I did everything still am getting same error

Comment: have you enabled multiDex to true in gradle?

Comment: yes I enabled even i updated my gradle still am getting same error